# I can't figure out why a for loop doesn't compile

Tags: c, loops

When i'm trying to compile this program i get two errors, one being:

```
main.c:34:24: error: expected expression before ')' token
```

and the other being:

```
main.c:34:24 error: expected ';' before ')' token
         for(i = 0,i<r,i++)<
```

This is my Code :

header:

```c
#ifndef HEADER1
#define HEADER1

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024
#define SP1 1
#define SP2 2

void eingabe_check();
int spieler_check(int *r);

#endif
```

main.c :

```c
#include "Header.h"

void eingabe_check() {

}
/* Überprüft welcher Spieler an der Reihe ist*/
int spieler_check(int *r) {
    if(0 < (*r % 2))
        return SP1;
    else 
        return SP2;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 1) {
        exit;
    }
    int a = 1,r = 1;
    int *b = &r;

    if(a && r) {
        int game[MAX_LEN];
        int s, i;
        switch(spieler_check(b)){
            case 1:
            case 2:
                printf("%s ist an der Reihe\n",argv[spieler_check(b)]);
                break;
            default:
                exit;
        }
        scanf("%i",game[r]);
        for(i = 0, i < r, i++)
            s += game[i];
        if(game[r] > 7 || game[r] == 0)
            printf("Es sind nur Zahlen zwischen 0 und 7 erlaubt\n");
        else if(s >= 21)
            printf("&s GEWINNT !!",argv[spieler_check(b-1)]);
        else
            r++;
    }

    else
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Might want to use semicolons instead of commas as separators between the three parts of the loop control.

Comment: The reason a `for` loop delimits the the clauses with semicolons rather than commas is that the comma is an operator.

Comment: OT: This `scanf("%i",game[r]);` looks wrong.

Comment: OT: This `s += game[i];` also looks wrong, as `s` had not been initialised.

Answer (score 6):

Change statement to `for(i = 0; i < r; i++)`